# Smart gwt grid grouping doesn't work when records are over 1000

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, smartgwt

Smart gwt grid grouping doesn't work when records are over 1000. 
Below 1000 grouping works fine. It's a multi-field grouping.

Any idea why's that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used method [setGroupByMaxRecords(int groupByMaxRecords)](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#setGroupByMaxRecords%28int%29) on your grid? It's default value is 1000 so i belive that might be the cause of your problem. Try setting it for a number bigger than 1000, for example:

```
ListGrid.setGroupByMaxRecords(2500);
```